# Python API Google drive image upload and insert to google doc gives error sometimes

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-docs-api, google-api-python-client

We are seeing below error intermittently.

```
Error has occur during upload <HttpError 400 when requesting https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents/1BDN80tikR7rsSG3ynvdywFCUojghqfG35wkwIeIXvfc:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid requests[0].insertInlineImage: Access to the provided image was forbidden.". Details: "Invalid requests[0].insertInlineImage: Access to the provided image was forbidden.">
```

Below is the python code we are using for image uploading and then getting the uploaded link.

```
 def upload_files(self, filename, filepath, folder_id):
   
    file_metadata = {
        "name": filename,
        "parents": [folder_id]
    }
    media = MediaFileUpload(filepath + filename, resumable=True)
    file = self.drive_service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='webContentLink, id, webViewLink').execute()
    self.drive_service.permissions().create(fileId=file.get('id'), body={'type': 'anyone', 'role': 'reader'}).execute()
    return file.get("webContentLink")
```

We are using insertInlineImage method to insert image to google doc. What is surprising is that same code works sometimes and fails sometimes. We have tried everything but not able to find the root cause. We are using Google Cloud Platform VM to run the scripts and currently we are on free subscription plan of $300 credits.

**Updated:**

Method to insert image at a specific index. Assume that index is a valid value.

```
def insert_image(self, start_index, url):
    request = [{
        'insertInlineImage': {
            'location': {
                'index': start_index
            },
            'uri':
                url,
                'objectSize': {
                 'height': {
                    'magnitude': 637,
                    'unit': 'PT'
                },   
                'width': {
                    'magnitude': 555,
                    'unit': 'PT'
                }
            }
        }
    }]
```

Comment: About `We are using insertInlineImage method to insert image to google doc.`, can you provide the script?

Comment: In addition to what Tanaike commented, could you please clarify if this error appears with different pictures?  Also, is that picture shared?

Comment: @Tanaike Updated the original code with the method where we are using insertInlineImage

Comment: @Jacques-GuzelHeron Error with same images intermittently.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding your script. In your script, how is the function `insert_image` called? Because I cannot understand whether the image of `url` is the valid image and the publicly shared. I apologize for this.

Comment: @Tanaike It is a valid URL as same URL works sometimes and sometimes not. Relevant public permissions is already being applied during upload as you can see in upload_files method. insert_image method is being called by passing the doc id and he URL received from upload_files method.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the sample URL you are using?